# Which Google document should be followed for Android icon sizes?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-actionbar-compat, android-icons

Google's [Android document on Iconography](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html) says that action bar icons should be 32x32 while [its document on Action Bar Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar) says that they should be 24x24 for the baseline that is presumably mdpi.

I thought that [Android document on Iconography](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html) was obsolete, but Google usually is good at marking obsolete/deprecate features.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I am hearing about the [site](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar) you are referring to. I believe it was the older version of "developer.android.com", since the home page of [the site](http://www.androiddocs.com/index.html), has "Android 5.0 Lollipop" in the banner. Not sure why the site is still up.

For iconography please follow [Action bar icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar) or https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html

Comment: Thank you.  It is interesting that the first link of your suggestion "please follow Android document on Iconography" points to the same web page in question.  I found the page by Googling. It was at the top of the search results.  I have forgot the exact search phrase.

Comment: @Hong Sorry for that. I copied the wrong link. Edited now.